# Save Document without closing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How do I save the current document as `docx` without closing through `saveAndClose()` first? I want to create multiple `docx` files from the same original Google Docs document on which my Script is running.

Comment: Just reaccess it

Comment: How do I do that? I'm really new to Google Scripts and there isn't much documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can export a docs to docx with URL fetch:

```
function myFunction() {

 var doc_id = 'YOUR DOCUMENT ID';
 var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' + doc_id + '&exportFormat=docx';
 var options = {
  headers: {
   Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  },
   muteHttpExceptions: true
 }
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 var doc = response.getBlob();
 DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName('myDocxFile1');
 DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName('myDocxFile2');
}
```

Comment: This creates two iidentical DocX files, both copies of the current document the last time it was saved. What I want is to have the script make changes to the document, save it, create a DocX copy, then make other changes and create another DocX.

Comment: Then you need to saveAndClose() it after every edit